# Outlook: How to move all mail from a certain recipient into Junk

Tags: ms-office, spam

How can I force Outlook to move all incoming messages with certain recipient to the Junk folder?

Answer (score 1):

Open Outlook (2011) Junk > Email protection.

Add the sender manually to the list.

[image]

or simply do this and select BLOCK sender.

[image]